# Why storage replica failover failed either use New-PSSession or Enter-PSSession

Tags: windows, powershell, cluster-computing, powershell-remoting, failovercluster

The following script will finish successfully, but after failover, the new DestinationComputer data volume still in mount state and the Replication status is "WaitingForDestination"

```
$cred = Get-Credential domain\adminaccount
$s = New-PSSession -computerName DestinationSrv01 -credential $cred
Invoke-Command -Session $s -Scriptblock {Set-SRPartnership -NewSourceComputerName DestinationSrv01 -SourceRGName rg02 -DestinationComputerName SourceSrv01 -DestinationRGName rg01 -confirm:$false}
Remove-PSSession $s
```

SourceSrv01:

```
DataVolume IsMounted ReplicationMode   ReplicationStatus
---------- --------- ---------------   -----------------
D:\                     Synchronous WaitingForDestination
```

I tested the same command using `Enter-PSSession`, the result is the same as above.

If I RDP to DestinationSrv01 and open PowerShell console run the following command, every is working.

```
Set-SRPartnership -NewSourceComputerName DestinationSrv01 -SourceRGName rg02 -DestinationComputerName SourceSrv01 -DestinationRGName rg01 -confirm:$false
```

SourceSrv01:

```
DataVolume IsMounted ReplicationMode     ReplicationStatus
---------- --------- ---------------     -----------------
D:\           False   Synchronous ContinuouslyReplicating
```

Comment: It's a guess but this may be a timing thing, and perhaps related to object serialization that's done with remoting. Try adding `| Get-SRPartnership` after the `Set-...` command in the script block.  Since it looks like the `Set-SRPartnership` command is outputting the object this should cause a refresh before it's returned through the session.

Comment: I changed my script add the Invoke-Command -Session $s -Scriptblock { Set-SRPartnership -NewSourceComputerName DestinationSrv01 -SourceRGName rg02 -DestinationComputerName SourceSrv01 -DestinationRGName rg01 -confirm:$false | Get-SRPartnership}
Start-Sleep -s 30
Remove-PSSession $s
I still have the same problem, this make both SourceSrv01 & DestinationSrv01 rw          DataVolume IsMounted ReplicationMode      ReplicationStatus
---------- --------- ---------------      -----------------
D:\                      Synchronous   WaitingForDestination

Answer (score 0):

I'm navigating blind here but with current comments and the suspicion of a timing issue try adjusting the position of `Start-Sleep`:

```
$cred = Get-Credential domain\adminaccount
$s = New-PSSession -computerName DestinationSrv01 -credential $cred

$ScriptBlock = {
    $SRPartnerShip = Set-SRPartnership -NewSourceComputerName DestinationSrv01 -SourceRGName rg02 -DestinationComputerName SourceSrv01 -DestinationRGName rg01 -confirm:$false
    Start-Sleep -Seconds 30
    $SRPartnerShip = $SRPartnerShip | Get-SRPartnership
}

Invoke-Command -Session $s -Scriptblock $ScriptBlock
Remove-PSSession $s
```

This waits 30 seconds before refreshing then returning. The way you had it you were waiting 30 seconds after the return. If the refresh via a simple re-get didn't fix it it wouldn't change anything except to wait longer to return bad info.

Comment: Thanks a lot Steven. I modified the script as you proposed and run it again. Same as before
DataVolume IsMounted ReplicationMode      ReplicationStatus
---------- --------- ---------------      -----------------
D:\                      Synchronous   WaitingForDestination

If failover from the RDP session console, the new Destination should looks like
DataVolume IsMounted ReplicationMode        ReplicationStatus
---------- --------- ---------------        -----------------
D:\            False     Synchronous   ContinuouslyReplicating

Comment: Sorry man, that was my best guess. I don't have a setup to code-storm this against.